# Count number of values in nested object

Tags: javascript

I have an object from Firebase that looks like this:

```
{
   "-M7OfUx9uE9Ly84iK1rF":{
      "dietRestrictions":"Vegetarian",
      "name":[
         "Josh",
         "Kaylyn",
         "Jack"
      ]
   },
   "-M7OnjC7CVMZiKJWeZyF":{
      "dietRestrictions":"",
      "name":[
         "TEST 1",
         "TEST 2"
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to count the total number of names in the object. The keys `-M7OnjC7CVMZiKJWeZyF` come from Firebase and are random. Also if the name is empty/undefined I do not want to count it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const data = {} // Your object
    let count = 0;
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      if(value.name && value.name.length > 0) {
        count += value.name.filter(Boolean).length;    
      }
    });
```

Comment: You can loop over the object and check each value whether the name is present and if present, just add length to cound

Comment: Thanks, this works except when their is an empty value `[empty, "Josh", "Kaylyn", "Jack"]`

Comment: `count += value.name.filter(Boolean).length;`

This is what I needed.

Comment: Ok, u mean element of name can be empty/undefined? I was thinking the name array can be empty

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.keys()`

```js
let obj = {
  "-M7OfUx9uE9Ly84iK1rF": {
    "dietRestrictions": "Vegetarian",
    "name": [
      "Josh",
      "Kaylyn",
      "Jack"
    ]
  },
  "-M7OnjC7CVMZiKJWeZyF": {
    "dietRestrictions": "",
    "name": [
      "TEST 1",
      "TEST 2"
    ]
  }
}
let count = 0;
Object.keys(obj).forEach(el => {
  if (obj[el].name && obj[el].name.length) count += obj[el].name.length
})
console.log(count) //5
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
      
    
    const response={
       "-M7OfUx9uE9Ly84iK1rF":{
          "dietRestrictions":"Vegetarian",
          "name":[
             "Josh",
             "Kaylyn",
             "Jack"
          ]
       },
       "-M7OnjC7CVMZiKJWeZyF":{
          "dietRestrictions":"",
          "name":[
             "TEST 1",
             "TEST 2"
          ]
       }
    };
    
     const countNumber = (obj) => {
          let count = 0;
          for (const key in obj) {
            if (Array.isArray(obj[key].name)) count += obj[key].name.length;
          }
          return count;
        };

    const output = countNumber(response);
    console.log(output)//5
```